# How to create a symbolic link or hard link to another symbolic link?

Tags: linux, symlink, symlink-traversal

For example, I create a link `ln -s /mytarget /mylink` (where `mytarget` is a directory). Now I would like to create a link to `/mylink`, i.e., `ln -s /mylink /mylinkother`. The first link `mylink` works fine, but the second link `mylinkother` does not work.

Related:

1. [Does creating a symbolic link to another symbolic link have any side-effects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4695241/does-creating-a-symbolic-link-to-another-symbolic-link-have-any-side-effects)
2. [How to create a link to a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9587445/how-to-create-a-link-to-a-directory)

Answer (score 0):

It actually works as I described on my first post. I was just pointing the symbolic link target, i.e., `ln -s /linktarget linknameother` to a non existing location. Once the `/linktarget` location was correct, my second link worked fine.

Comment: Good job solving the issue yourself. However, since the question was the result of "operator error" you may want to go ahead and delete or close it. I won't downvote, but other may not be so restrained. (not to mention the question relates to general software use and not a programming question per-se...)